# MySQL: Obtain Fields From Multiple Tables Each Result Represented As A Row

Tags: mysql

I have multiple tables with this structure:

```
+----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| nick     | char(25) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| id       | int(11)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| cooldown | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I would like to obtain all of the `id` fields from all of these tables given a `nick`. These tables (lets call them `table1`, `table2`, `table3`) may or may not be empty. What is the best way to do this in one query?

My desired output would look like:

```
+-------+
| id    |
+-------+
| 15679 |
| 72620 |
+-------+
```

Comment: Paste the sample data in those all tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) query:

```
SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE nick='nick'
UNION
SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE nick='nick'
UNION
SELECT id FROM table3 WHERE nick='nick'
```

`UNION` will only return unique rows, if you want your query to return duplicates you can use `UNION ALL` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Id from table1 where nick=nick
UNION
Select Id from table2 where nick=nick
UNION
...
UNION
...
```